# Обработка (ресайз/копирование). Более 32к изображений (Joomla, ООП)

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, joomla, изображения

Требуется обработать большое кол-во изображений. На данный момент имеется следующее:

/* ПЕРЕНОС И ПОДГОТОВКА ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЙ */

```
public function getImages() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "SELECT `product_id` FROM `#__jshopping_products`";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $prodImages = $db->loadAssocList();
    foreach ($prodImages as $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $imageList[] .= $value;
        }
    }
    foreach ($imageList as $value) {
        for($try = 0; $try < 5; $try++) {
            $tech = self::imageExist($value, $try);
            if($tech === true) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

private function imageExist($name, $try) {
    switch($try) {
        case 0:
            $img = _SDIR .''.$name.'.jpg';
            $file = $name.'.jpg';
            break;
        case 1:
            $img = _SDIR .''.$name.'.jpeg';
            $file = $name.'.jpeg';
            break;
        case 2:
            $img = _SDIR .''.$name.'.JPG';
            $file = $name.'.JPG';
            break;
        case 3:
            $img = _SDIR .''.$name.'.png';
            $file = $name.'.png';
            break;
        case 4:
            $img = _SDIR .''.$name.'.PNG';
            $file = $name.'.PNG';
            break;
        case 5:
            return false;
    }

    if(file_exists($img)) {
        self::prepareImages($file);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private function prepareImages($file) {

    $fileExp = '';
    $src_file = explode('.', $file);
    switch(end($src_file)) {
        case 'JPG':
            $img = self::checkImage($file);
            $fileExp = 'JPG';
            break;
        case 'jpg':
            $img = self::checkImage($file);
            $fileExp = 'jpg';
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            $img = self::checkImage($file);
            $fileExp = 'jpeg';
            break;
        case 'png':
            $img = self::checkImage($file);
            $fileExp = 'png';
            break;
        case 'PNG':
            $img = self::checkImage($file); 
            $fileExp = 'PNG';
            break;
        default:
            die('');
    }

    $imgs = self::getSize($img);
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 800);

    imagecopy($dest, $img, (800 - $imgs['w'])/2, (800 - $imgs['h'])/2, 0, 0, $imgs['w'], $imgs['h']);

    $newfile = _TDIR . $src_file[0] . "." . "$fileExp";
    $nimg = self::imgScale($img, _WH_PRODUCT, _WH_PRODUCT);
    imagejpeg($nimg, $newfile);

    $thumb_file = _TDIR . "thumb_" . $src_file[0] . "." . "$fileExp";
    $timg = self::imgScale($img, _WH_THUMBS, _WH_THUMBS);
    imagejpeg($timg, $thumb_file);

    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($nimg);
    imagedestroy($timg);

    // unlink($file);
}

# Среднее разрешение
private static function imgScale($file, $mw, $mh)
{
    $f = self::getSize($file);
    $wr = $mw / $f['w'];
    $hr = $mh / $f['h'];
    if($wr < $hr)
    {
        $nw = floor($f['w'] * $wr);
        $nh = floor($f['h'] * $wr);
        return self::res($nw, $nh, $file);
    }
    else
    {
        $nw = floor($f['w'] * $hr);
        $nh = floor($f['h'] * $hr);
        return self::res($nw, $nh, $file);
    }
    return false;
}

# Изменяем разрешение изображения с учетом ширина-высота
private static function res($width, $height, $file)
{
    return imagescale($file, $width, $height);
}

# Получаем размер изображения
private static function getSize($src)
{
    $x = imagesx($src);
    $y = imagesy($src);
    return array("w" => "$x", "h" => "$y");
}

private static function checkImage($file) {
    $imginfo = getimagesize(_SDIR.''.$file);
    $mime = $imginfo[mime];
    if($mime == 'image/jpeg') {
        return imagecreatefromjpeg(_SDIR . $file);
    } else if($mime == 'image/png') {
        return imagecreatefrompng(_SDIR . $file);
    } else if($mime == 'image/gif') {
        return imagecreatefromgif(_SDIR . $file);
    }
}
```

Все это дело слетает через 30 секунд обработки, ограничения на стороне сервера. Увеличить время пока не дают. Может кто посоветует способ оптимизации данного процесса.

Суть такая:

1. лезем в БД и достаем все ID товаров
2. ищем в SOURCE папке (_SDIR) файл с таким названием
3. сохраняем суженный до размеров 800х800 (_WH_PRODUCT) оригинал и 240х240 (_WH_THUMBS) превьюшку в папку _TDIR.

Comment: А вы запустите скрипт с браузера. Обработали 10 изображений отправили ответ браузеру на перезагрузку страницы и так в цикле пока все изображения не обработаете ;) Или выполняйте данную перекодировку по мере обращения к изображениям: нет изображения на месте -> запускаем скрипт на создание.

Comment: Да я так думал, но сложность в том, что это не единичная проверка. И так кучу проблем подкинули с файлами, типо gif файл переименованный в png... Так что все надо сделать автоматически и прогонять раз в неделю )

Comment: Любая очередь подойдёт  Gearman, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ ... Можно через крон запускать скрипт который будет по 5 изображений за раз делать.

Comment: Как вариант, но хотелось бы найти более эстетическое решение на стороне скрипта

Comment: Дело в том что правильное решение это очереди. Легко паралеляться, полный контроль, ни какой магии.  FYI: CLI (запушенные из командной строки) php скрипты обычно не ограничены по времени!

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Если другого варианта не найду, то так и поступлю